# How to store and display image in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls

In my WPF application I would like to upload images. The specifications are,

1. PNG or JPEG formate
2. < 200KB
3. rename the image
4. save into the `Images` folder of application's root directory.
   then,
5. display the image into an `Image` control named as `image-1`

Would you please give me a simple way to do this.

Comment: what technique did u try, and why u did not like it ?

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You add your images to a img subfolder
2. In your global Style file you add your images

   `<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImage" Source="..\MyImage.png" />`
3. Reference the Image by using a Static Resource

   `<Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyImage}" />`

Comment: i need the image source to be set dynamically. i mean, from the code behind file.

Comment: so set an collection of BitmapImage and bind the selected on to the <Image> source

Comment: Or just bind the Source of your Image to a property in your ViewModel and then Load the Bitmap from the style into your property.